# Gnuplot erases circles when zoomed in

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I am trying to plot a file of data along with 2 circles with gnuplot. The data file is [here](https://ufile.io/36pvmhvl) and the circle file is [here](https://ufile.io/5m7yu80b). The circles are quite big compared to the dataset, and when I plot it on a large scale everything works fine. But when I try to zoom in, the circles disappear. Here are the gnuplot commands I use (v5.4.2):

```
plot 'data.txt' us (log($2)):(log($3)) w lp, 'circ.txt' us 1:2:3 w circles
```

Here is the result (looks ok):

[image: pic1]

Now if I try to zoom in a little (still ok):

```
set xrange [*:55]
replot
```

[image: pic2]

Trying to zoom in more (circles disappear!)

```
set xrange [*:8]
replot
```

[image: pic3]

Is this a bug in gnuplot, or is there a way to fix this and visualize the circles on a zoomed in view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gnuplot does not draw points that are out of range.  You can think of a circle as a point defined by its center and radius.  As soon as the center goes out of range, in this case xmin < xmax < center, the circle is no longer drawn.

Answer (score 1):

As @Ethan already explained, with the plotting style `with circles` if the center of a circle is not in the graph range anymore, the circle will not be plotted.

You can workaround this if you plot the circles yourself. Then you can zoom in as long as a datapoint of the circumference is still in the graph. For large zoom-in you could increase the number of samples, e.g. `set samples 500`.

However, in order to have the circle visually appear as a circle (not as an ellipse) you have to `set size ratio -1` which will change the graph size.

**Code:**

```
### plot circles which "allow" zoom-in
reset session
set size ratio -1

$Circles <<EOD
 50  0   50
100  0  100
220  0  220
EOD

CircX(x0,y0,r,t) = x0+r*cos(2*pi*t) 
CircY(x0,y0,r,t) = y0+r*sin(2*pi*t) 
x0(n) = word($Circles[n],1)
y0(n) = word($Circles[n],2)
r(n)  = word($Circles[n],3)

set key noautotitle
set samples 100
set yrange[-100:100]

plot for [i=1:|$Circles|] [0:1] '+' u \
    (CircX(x0(i),y0(i),r(i),$1)):(CircY(x0(i),y0(i),r(i),$1)) w l
### end of code
```

**Result:** (original plot)

[image]

**(zoomed-in):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Another solution using 'set object circle'

There is a way to display all circles defined in 'circ.txt' as objects using `set object circle`.

```
set table $DATA
plot "circ.txt" using 1:2:3 with table
unset table

do for [k=1:|$DATA|] {
   line = $DATA[k]
   xpos = word(line, 1)
   ypos = word(line, 2)
   r    = word(line, 3)
   set object circle at xpos, ypos radius r fill empty border lc black
}

set xrange [*:30]
set yrange [*:16]

plot "data.txt" using (log($2)):(log($3)) with lp
```

[image]